# Python not considering reverse order values as duplicates

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

How to make python understand the reverse order of a word in the column is a duplicate of the correct order.

ex: 3 rd row is actually a duplicate of the other two. But when I take value_counts it's being treated as a separate entity.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Rzecx.png)

Comment: Please provide a real example as text or better DataFrame constructor. A solution would be to sort the split string

Answer (score 0):

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'id': [1,2], 'desc': ['xx ,yy', 'yy, xx']}) # example dataset
df
```

[image]

df.desc.value_counts()

[image]

Lets create a new column with cleanned data:

```
df['desc_clean'] = None # create a new column
for i, v in df.desc.iteritems(): # iterate over all tiems of the [desc] column
    split_list = v.split(',') # split each string on the ',' return array of strings between ','
    split_clean_list = [i.strip() for i in split_list] # remove white characters(spaces, tabs...) from begining and end
    sorted_list = sorted(split_clean_list) # sort the list 
    new_string = ', '.join(sorted_list) # create a new sorted string from list items, separated by ', '
    df.at[i, 'desc_clean'] =  new_string # insert data to new column, you can also update the existing 'desc' column
```

Now the data frame has a new column with sorted description:
[image]

and the value_counts on it works as you want:
`df.desc_clean.value_counts()`
[image]